# What are allowed properties on neo4j nodes and relationships?

Tags: neo4j

Some things i noticed while trying out some different properties

An array of objects as value does not work

```
create (n {foo: [{baz:"fox"}, {baz:"quix"}] })<-[:a]-() return n
```

An array of values as value does work

```
create (n {foo: ["bar", "baz"] })<-[:a]-() return n
```

And array of object does not work

```
create (n [{baz:"fox"}, {baz:"bar"}] )<-[:a]-() return n
```

Where can i get the full specification of what is and what is not allowed? Obviously "it's just JSON" doesn't fly. Also you can not quote the property keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can java primitive types, String or array of those as property values. See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/property-values-detailed.html for details.